# how to import data from mongodb to hive

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I would like to know how to import data from Mongodb to hive with the help of mapreduce programs.previousley i was imported data from mongodb to hdfs with the help of mapreduce program,now i want import data directley from mongodb to hive.
I really appreciate If someone able to share any reference document for this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try to be more elaborate. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Mongo-Hadoop connector](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Hive-Usage). It permits you use Mongo as backend storage for Hive (you could query data stored in MongoDB with Hive).

If you really need to import data into Hive you'd first need to create a (temporary) Hive table with mongo collection from where you are going to import data as backend. Then you can import data into another Hive table with Hive CTAS query.